# Simple calculation in GDB yields inconsistent results

Tags: c, gdb

I am attempting to debug the following line of code in GDB:

```
p=((uint32 *) tiff_pixels)+image->columns*i;
```

`p i` yeilds `8`

`p columns` yeilds `32`

`p image->columns*i` correctly yields `256`

`p ((uint32 *) tiff_pixels)` yields `0x619000008780`

so I expect `((uint32 *) tiff_pixels)+image->columns*i` to yield `0x619000008880` but I get `0x619000008b80` instead.

I am probably making some trivial error/assumption here but I cannot seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to multiply by the size of each pixel, which is 4 bytes.

```
p=((uint32 *) tiff_pixels)+image->columns*i;
```

You've cast `tiff_pixels` to be a pointer to a `uint32`. Each `uint32` is four bytes. So if you add one to the pointer, it will point to the *next* `uint32`, which is four bytes after the first one.

Comment: Right! Thank you. I will mark this as the right answer once I am able to.